# Previously mountable GlusterFS volume now fails to mount with several errors

Tags: mount, glusterfs, fstab

I've previously set up a couple of GlusterFS volumes (called `cyclorana0` and `cyclorana1`) across two nodes (with IPs `10.0.2.4` (hostname `alboguttata`) and `10.0.2.5` (hostname `verrucosa`)) on my LAN. The `probe` commands, etc. were successful and the two nodes can see each other and the volumes correctly. The two nodes are running Armbian Linux 4.14.144-odroidxu4 with `glusterfs-server` version 3.13.2-1ubuntu1.

I've also set up a RHEL client (with `glusterfs` packages version 3.12.2) to mount the volumes via `/etc/fstab`, and it's been working fine for several months, even after several reboots. Here's the contents:

```
10.0.2.5:/cyclorana0 /home/[username]/cyclorana0 glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
10.0.2.5:/cyclorana1 /home/[username]/cyclorana1 glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

However, after a reboot of the RHEL client yesterday, the mounts fail. After I tried manually running `mount -a`, I only get this:

```
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
```

The only logs I can think of are those in `/var/log/glusterfs/`, and indeed I found log files corresponding to my attempts. The output for the two volumes are the same, so here is one of them for example:

```
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.834507] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2646:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.12.2 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=10.0.2.5 --volfile-id=/cyclorana1 /home/[username]/cyclorana1)
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.844494] W [MSGID: 101002] [options.c:995:xl_opt_validate] 0-glusterfs: option 'address-family' is deprecated, preferred is 'transport.address-family', continuing with correction
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.863736] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:676:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 0
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.863931] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:676:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 1
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.873312] I [MSGID: 114020] [client.c:2361:notify] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: parent translators are ready, attempting connect on transport
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.883477] E [MSGID: 101075] [common-utils.c:482:gf_resolve_ip6] 0-resolver: getaddrinfo failed (family:2) (Name or service not known)
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.883561] E [name.c:267:af_inet_client_get_remote_sockaddr] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: DNS resolution failed on host verrucosa
Final graph:
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1: volume cyclorana1-client-0
  2:     type protocol/client
  3:     option ping-timeout 42
  4:     option remote-host verrucosa
  5:     option remote-subvolume /bricks/brick1
  6:     option transport-type socket
  7:     option transport.address-family inet
  8:     option transport.tcp-user-timeout 0
  9:     option transport.socket.keepalive-time 20
 10:     option transport.socket.keepalive-interval 2
 11:     option transport.socket.keepalive-count 9
 12:     option send-gids true
 13: end-volume
 14:  
 15: volume cyclorana1-dht
 16:     type cluster/distribute
 17:     option lock-migration off
 18:     subvolumes cyclorana1-client-0
 19: end-volume
 20:  
 21: volume cyclorana1-write-behind
 22:     type performance/write-behind
 23:     subvolumes cyclorana1-dht
 24: end-volume
 25:  
 26: volume cyclorana1-read-ahead
 27:     type performance/read-ahead
 28:     subvolumes cyclorana1-write-behind
 29: end-volume
 30:  
 31: volume cyclorana1-readdir-ahead
 32:     type performance/readdir-ahead
 33:     option parallel-readdir off
 34:     option rda-request-size 131072
 35:     option rda-cache-limit 10MB
 36:     subvolumes cyclorana1-read-ahead
 37: end-volume
 38:  
 39: volume cyclorana1-io-cache
 40:     type performance/io-cache
 41:     subvolumes cyclorana1-readdir-ahead
 42: end-volume
 43:  
 44: volume cyclorana1-quick-read
 45:     type performance/quick-read
 46:     subvolumes cyclorana1-io-cache
 47: end-volume
 48:  
 49: volume cyclorana1-open-behind
 50:     type performance/open-behind
 51:     subvolumes cyclorana1-quick-read
 52: end-volume
 53:  
 54: volume cyclorana1-md-cache
 55:     type performance/md-cache
 56:     subvolumes cyclorana1-open-behind
 57: end-volume
 58:  
 59: volume cyclorana1-io-threads
 60:     type performance/io-threads
 61:     subvolumes cyclorana1-md-cache
 62: end-volume
 63:  
 64: volume cyclorana1
 65:     type debug/io-stats
 66:     option log-level INFO
 67:     option latency-measurement off
 68:     option count-fop-hits off
 69:     subvolumes cyclorana1-io-threads
 70: end-volume
 71:  
 72: volume meta-autoload
 73:     type meta
 74:     subvolumes cyclorana1
 75: end-volume
 76:  
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.887159] I [fuse-bridge.c:4915:fuse_init] 0-glusterfs-fuse: FUSE inited with protocol versions: glusterfs 7.24 kernel 7.23
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.887257] I [fuse-bridge.c:5548:fuse_graph_sync] 0-fuse: switched to graph 0
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.887755] E [fuse-bridge.c:4983:fuse_first_lookup] 0-fuse: first lookup on root failed (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.891025] W [fuse-bridge.c:1242:fuse_attr_cbk] 0-glusterfs-fuse: 2: LOOKUP() / => -1 (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.896995] W [fuse-bridge.c:1242:fuse_attr_cbk] 0-glusterfs-fuse: 3: LOOKUP() / => -1 (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.905103] I [fuse-bridge.c:5822:fuse_thread_proc] 0-fuse: initating unmount of /home/[username]/cyclorana1
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.905610] W [glusterfsd.c:1462:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7f2075213ea5] -->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_sigwaiter+0xe5) [0x557ca6064d05] -->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(cleanup_and_exit+0x6b) [0x557ca6064b6b] ) 0-: received signum (15), shutting down
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.905659] I [fuse-bridge.c:6611:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/home/[username]/cyclorana1'.
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.905685] I [fuse-bridge.c:6616:fini] 0-fuse: Closing fuse connection to '/home/[username]/cyclorana1'.
```

I can barely understand these logs, but from what I can tell, my RHEL client can "see" the volume but somehow couldn't mount it. The main problematic lines in the log seem to be (tell me if I'm wrong):

```
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.883477] E [MSGID: 101075] [common-utils.c:482:gf_resolve_ip6] 0-resolver: getaddrinfo failed (family:2) (Name or service not known)
[2019-09-21 02:21:59.883561] E [name.c:267:af_inet_client_get_remote_sockaddr] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: DNS resolution failed on host verrucosa
```

I'm baffled by the `DNS resolution` error, since I'm connecting directly via it's LAN IP and the RHEL client is on the same LAN.

I also tried to mount from a separate Manjaro Linux client on the same LAN which produced the same error messages.

How do I troubleshoot and fix this so that I can mount these volumes? Thank you.

P.S. Here is a log from when the mount was *successful*:

```
[2019-08-27 06:07:08.806469] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2646:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.12.2 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=10.0.2.5 --volfile-id=/cyclorana1 /home/[username]/cyclorana1)
[2019-08-27 06:07:09.225314] W [MSGID: 101002] [options.c:995:xl_opt_validate] 0-glusterfs: option 'address-family' is deprecated, preferred is 'transport.address-family', continuing with correction
[2019-08-27 06:07:09.377519] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:676:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 0
[2019-08-27 06:07:09.379969] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:676:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 1
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.809517] I [MSGID: 114020] [client.c:2361:notify] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: parent translators are ready, attempting connect on transport
Final graph:
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1: volume cyclorana1-client-0
  2:     type protocol/client
  3:     option ping-timeout 42
  4:     option remote-host verrucosa
  5:     option remote-subvolume /bricks/brick1
  6:     option transport-type socket
  7:     option transport.address-family inet
  8:     option transport.tcp-user-timeout 0
  9:     option transport.socket.keepalive-time 20
 10:     option transport.socket.keepalive-interval 2
 11:     option transport.socket.keepalive-count 9
 12:     option send-gids true
 13: end-volume
 14:  
 15: volume cyclorana1-dht
 16:     type cluster/distribute
 17:     option lock-migration off
 18:     subvolumes cyclorana1-client-0
 19: end-volume
 20:  
 21: volume cyclorana1-write-behind
 22:     type performance/write-behind
 23:     subvolumes cyclorana1-dht
 24: end-volume
 25:  
 26: volume cyclorana1-read-ahead
 27:     type performance/read-ahead
 28:     subvolumes cyclorana1-write-behind
 29: end-volume
 30:  
 31: volume cyclorana1-readdir-ahead
 32:     type performance/readdir-ahead
 33:     option parallel-readdir off
 34:     option rda-request-size 131072
 35:     option rda-cache-limit 10MB
 36:     subvolumes cyclorana1-read-ahead
 37: end-volume
 38:  
 39: volume cyclorana1-io-cache
 40:     type performance/io-cache
 41:     subvolumes cyclorana1-readdir-ahead
 42: end-volume
 43:  
 44: volume cyclorana1-quick-read
 45:     type performance/quick-read
 46:     subvolumes cyclorana1-io-cache
 47: end-volume
 48:  
 49: volume cyclorana1-open-behind
 50:     type performance/open-behind
 51:     subvolumes cyclorana1-quick-read
 52: end-volume
 53:  
 54: volume cyclorana1-md-cache
 55:     type performance/md-cache
 56:     subvolumes cyclorana1-open-behind
 57: end-volume
 58:  
 59: volume cyclorana1-io-threads
 60:     type performance/io-threads
 61:     subvolumes cyclorana1-md-cache
 62: end-volume
 63:  
 64: volume cyclorana1
 65:     type debug/io-stats
 66:     option log-level INFO
 67:     option latency-measurement off
 68:     option count-fop-hits off
 69:     subvolumes cyclorana1-io-threads
 70: end-volume
 71:  
 72: volume meta-autoload
 73:     type meta
 74:     subvolumes cyclorana1
 75: end-volume
 76:  
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.825446] I [rpc-clnt.c:2013:rpc_clnt_reconfig] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: changing port to 49153 (from 0)
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.836134] I [MSGID: 114057] [client-handshake.c:1397:select_server_supported_programs] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: Using Program GlusterFS 3.3, Num (1298437), Version (330)
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.839068] I [MSGID: 114046] [client-handshake.c:1150:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: Connected to cyclorana1-client-0, attached to remote volume '/bricks/brick1'.
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.839149] I [MSGID: 114047] [client-handshake.c:1161:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: Server and Client lk-version numbers are not same, reopening the fds
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.840019] I [MSGID: 114035] [client-handshake.c:121:client_set_lk_version_cbk] 0-cyclorana1-client-0: Server lk version = 1
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.863385] I [fuse-bridge.c:4915:fuse_init] 0-glusterfs-fuse: FUSE inited with protocol versions: glusterfs 7.24 kernel 7.23
[2019-08-27 06:07:10.863513] I [fuse-bridge.c:5548:fuse_graph_sync] 0-fuse: switched to graph 0
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? What was the solution?

Comment: @TonyStark: Sorry the ending was anticlimatic, I just rebooted my server a few times and the problem disappeared...